# Cannot resolve typescript module using React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So i recentry decided to start a new React proyect but using typescript however when compiling there is an error:

```
./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components' in 'D:\path\to\proyect\src'
```

whats funny is that both Webstorm and VS code mark no issue whe importing the module but i get that not found error at copile time

the index.d.ts looks like this

```
module "components" {
import App from "./app/App";
import Home from "./home/Home";

export const AppComponent = App;
export const HomeComponent = Home;
}
```

I'm trying to avoid is having to write all the path to the components in somo folder like *./dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/etc*

tsconfig:

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "es2015",
"jsx": "react",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true
},
"include": [
"src"
]}
```

folder structure:

```
src/
   |───components
   |   |───index.d.ts
   │   |───app 
   |   └───home
   └───hooks
```

Comment: What do you mean "at compile time"? `component/index.d.ts` is wrong. It _must_ be a source file `.ts`. it cannot be a `.d.ts` file or it will never work. Also, it must look like this (All at the top level!): `export {default as App} from "./app/App"; export {default as Home} from "./home/Home";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is i was declaring constants and exporting modules in the `index.d.ts` however that file is only for type definitions that why Webstorm and VS code had no issue with the file since they will assume it was a module declaration but the compiler never expects to find module export in a `d.ts` file.

Solution is just to remove the `*.d.*` in the filename and rename it something like `module.ts` doing the corresponding imports and exports